# Uses of さあ、まあ and なんか

Tags: interjections

I understand meaning and uses of あの、えと。 But I get confused when people use さあ、まあ and なんか frequently while talking.

Comment: `なか`<- You mean なんか, no?

Comment: @chocolate May be なんか, but when they talk it sounds like なか. I am beginner so you should correct me なか or なんか

Answer (score 4):

If I get your question right,

**さあ** Can mean :

> - Who knows / I don't know
> - Ok now/ there we go

And perhaps a few more, depending on the intonation.
Example:

> Aさん:この人は誰？Bさん：さあね～。
>   Mr. A : Who is that? Mr. B : Who knows.

**まあ** Can mean :

> - Now now(mother reassuring kid)
> - Sort of, kinda.
> - oh, my!(Usually used by baasan)

And perhaps a few more, depending on the intonation.
Example:

> Aさん:うまくいった？Bさん：まあね～。
>   Mr. A : Did it go well? Mr. B : Kinda.

As for naka, perhaps you meant nanka.
It is hard to explain, but can be used to mean things like **you know** or **sort of**.
Example:

> Aさん:どうしたの？Bさん：なんかさ～、今朝から具合が悪いんだよ。
>   Mr. A : What's wrong? Mr. B : You know, I kinda don't feel good since this morning.

Comment: Thanks, and what about なか/なんか (I am beginner so don't know なか or なんか)